# Google ads javascript moving page scroll to top

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-ads-api

In my web page google ads are present and in the url hash tag is present . Initially when page loads it scrolls to that DIV having id equal to url hash tag then google ads are loaded which moves the page to top. How I can fix the problem of page getting scrolled to top.

Comment: Get rid of all ads - not only from Google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out Google ads was not the issue instead other third party javascript was the main issue behind it. 
I overrided scrollTo function in global object window as soon as the page loaded with mentioned script below. Due to which I was able to figure the root cause of the problem.

```
window.scrollTo = function(){
    console.log("Overriding started");
    debugger;
    console.log("Overriding end");
}
```